# GCC strange behaviour of move constructed object

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, clang++

Unfortunately I haven't been able to reduce the complexity of this problem, so the code for it is rather long-ish. The core of the problem is the test that I'm running.

```
TEST(Iterator, enumerator_rvalue)
{
  std::size_t index1 = 5;
  for (auto item : nr::enumerate(nr::range<std::size_t>(5, 27))) {
    ASSERT_EQ(index1 - 5, item.index);
    ASSERT_EQ(index1++, item.value);
  }
  ASSERT_EQ(index1, 27);
}
```

The assertion fails in the second iteration of the `for` loop when compiled with GCC 5 and 6 but works on Clang 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 (test on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/NiklasRosenstein/cpp-nr/builds/182386791)) and MSVC 2015 (test on [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/NiklasRosenstein/cpp-nr/build/1.0.39), the test case name is `Iterator.enumerator_rvalue`).

I've copied all the necessary code into a single file to replicate it on Coliru and added a few small prints and a temporary implementation for `ASSERT_EQ()`

- [Coliru with g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2e7ac911e327a13) fails
- [Coliru with clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/420391fa63fe95b1) works

---

To describe what the code is doing: `nr::range` is an iterator that simply iterates from `start` to `end-1`. `nr::enumerate()` produces an `nr::enumerator` that accepts an **rvalue** of an `Iterable`. Thus in this case the `nr::range` object will be *moved* to the `nr::enumerator::iter` member.

```
nr::enumerate(nr::range<std::size_t>(5, 27))
```

The `nr::enumerator` now simply wraps the iterator and the value that is being yielded by `nr::range` in an `nr::enumerator::item` object to associate it with an index.

These are the first two lines printed in the for loop on Clang:

```
index1=5, item.index:0, item.value:5
index1=6, item.index:1, item.value:6
```

With GCC, it is

```
index1=5, item.index:0, item.value:5
index1=6, item.index:1, item.value:1
```

Now the most interesting part IMO is that when I comment (aka remove) the `ASSERT_EQ()` statements, GCC also prints the correct values

```
index1=5, item.index:0, item.value:5
index1=5, item.index:1, item.value:6
```

---

**Now the question**: Is this a GCC bug or am I triggering undefined behaviour?

I've also considered the possibility that my own `ASSERT_EQ()` macro is going bonkers, but I can't find an issue with it, and that would also not explain the fails with googletest on Travis and AppVeyor.

---

*Edit*: I'll include the code here in case the Coliru links break (@NathanOliver). Simply copy&paste into a file and do `(g|clang)++ -std=c++(11|14) main.cpp && ./a.out`

```
#include <iostream>

// Copyright (c) 2016  Niklas Rosenstein
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
//
// @file nr/iterator.h
// @created 2016-01-21
// @lastmodified 2016-06-06

//#pragma once
#include <cassert>

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// @macro NR_ITERATOR_NOTYPETRAITS
//
// If this macro is defined, #<type_traits> will not but used. This requires
// the implementor of the #nr::iterator interface to manually specify the
// datatype that the `operator * ()` (dereference operator) will return
// as `yield_type`.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef NR_ITERATOR_NOTYPETRAITS
  #include <type_traits>
#endif


namespace nr {

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The #self_iterator is an adapter class from a new style iterator
// interface to the C++ iterator interface. It can be subclassed to
// implement iterator objects with the following interface:
//
// - `at_end() const`
// - `next()`
// - `X operator * () const`
//
// The first two methods will be used by the #self_iterator methods
// #operator++(), #operator!=() and #operator bool() to adapt to the
// C++ iterator interface. The dereference operator is required by
// the C++ iterator interface directly.
//
// This class should be used when implementing a simple iterator.
// However, the calls to #begin() and #end() will cause a copy of
// the iterator to be created, thus it will be problematic if your
// iterator allocates and frees resources automatically.
//
// For such cases, use the #iterator instead.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
class self_iterator
{
public:

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns false if the iterator is at its end, true otherwise.
  // This method calls #at_end(). Note that #at_end() must be declared
  // `const` if this operator is used.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline operator bool () const {
    return !static_cast<T const*>(this)->at_end();
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Used by the standard C++ iterator interface. Calls `at_end()` to
  // check if the end of the iterator was reached.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline bool operator != (self_iterator const&) {
    return !static_cast<T*>(this)->at_end();
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Increment operator. Calls `next()` to advance to the next element.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  self_iterator& operator ++ () {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->next();
    return *this;
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // C++ iterator interface.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // @{
  T& begin() { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
  T& end() { return *static_cast<T*>(this); }
  // @}

};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This class represents an adapter of the C++ iterator interface
// for new style iterator classes.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class iterator_adapter
{

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Pointer to the iterator implementation.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  T* itimpl;

public:

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // @typedef yield_type
  //
  // This type represents the datatype that is yielded by the iterator.
  // If #NR_ITERATOR_NOTYPETRAITS is defined, #<type_traits> will not be
  // used and #T must provide the #yield_type instead.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #ifdef NR_ITERATOR_NOTYPETRAITS
    typedef typename T::yield_type yield_type;
  #else
    typedef typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::operator *)(T)>::type yield_type;
  #endif

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Passing nullptr to this constructor represents creates a
  // sentinel iterator that marks the end of the iteration.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline iterator_adapter(T* itimpl) : itimpl(nullptr)
  {
    if (itimpl && !itimpl->at_end()) {
      this->itimpl = itimpl;
    }
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Calls `next()` and `at_end()` on the iterator implementation
  // to advance to the next item and check if the end of the iteration
  // has been reached.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline iterator_adapter& operator ++ ()
  {
    assert(this->itimpl != nullptr);
    this->itimpl->next();
    if (this->itimpl->at_end()) {
      this->itimpl = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline bool operator != (iterator_adapter const& other) const
  {
    return this->itimpl != other.itimpl;
  }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline yield_type operator * () const
  {
    assert(this->itimpl != nullptr);
    return this->itimpl->operator * ();
  }

};


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is an extension of the #self_iterator that uses an
// #iterator_adapter class for #begin() and #end() instead.
// It should be used when employing an iterator that allocates and
// frees resource dynamically.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
class iterator : public self_iterator<T>
{
public:

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns the #iterator_adapter for this iterator implementation.
  // It does not really mark the begin of the iteration, rather the
  // current state of the iterator.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline iterator_adapter<T> begin() { return iterator_adapter<T>(static_cast<T*>(this)); }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns the sentinel #iterator_adapter that marks the end of
  // the iteration.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline iterator_adapter<T> end() const { return iterator_adapter<T>(nullptr); }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Returns false if the iterator is at its end, true otherwise.
  // This method calls #at_end(). Note that #at_end() must be declared
  // `const` if this operator is used.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline operator bool () const {
    return !static_cast<T const*>(this)->at_end();
  }

};

} // namespace nr
// Copyright (c) 2016  Niklas Rosenstein
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
//
// @file <nr/iterator/range.h>
// @created 2016-07-02
// @brief Provides the #nr::range iterator class.

//#pragma once
//#include "../iterator.h"
#include <iterator>

namespace nr {

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// An implementation of a range iterator using the #nr::iterator
// interface. Supports an arbitrary integer dataype that can be
// specified with the template parameter #T.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class range : public iterator<range<T>>
{
  T curr, max, step;

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Simple function to retrieve the sign of a function.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  static int sign(T val) { return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0)); }

public:

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Create a range iterator starting from zero up excluding #max.
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline range(T max) : curr(0), max(max), step(1) { std::cout << "range()\n"; }

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Create a range iterator starting from #min up to excluding #max
  // taking the specified #step each turn (must not be zero and the
  // sign must match the direction of the iteration).
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inline range(T min, T max, T step = 1) : curr(min), max(max), step(step)
  {
    assert(step != 0 && sign(step) == sign(max - min));
    std::cout << "range()\n"; 
  }



  inline ~range() {
      std::cout << "~range()\n"; 
  }

public:  // nr::iterator overrides

  inline bool at_end() const { return this->curr >= this->max; }

  inline void next() { this->curr += step; }

  inline T operator * () const { return this->curr; }
};

} // namespace nr




// Copyright (c) 2016  Niklas Rosenstein
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
/*!
* @file <nr/iterator/enumerate.h>
* @created 2016-12-08
* @brief Python's `enumerate()` like iterator.
*/

//#pragma once
//#include "../iterator.h"

namespace nr {

  /*!
  * Implementation of the iterator behind #enumerate().
  */
  template <class Iterable>
  class enumerator : public nr::iterator<enumerator<Iterable>>
  {
    Iterable iter;
    std::size_t index;
    decltype(std::begin(iter)) iter_begin;
    decltype(std::end(iter)) const iter_end;

  public: // types

    struct item
    {
      std::size_t index;
      decltype(*iter_begin) value;
    };

  public:

    enumerator(Iterable&& iter_)
    : iter(std::move(iter_)), index(0), iter_begin(std::begin(iter_))
    , iter_end(std::end(iter_)) {}

    bool at_end() const { return !(this->iter_begin != this->iter_end); }

    void next() { ++this->iter_begin; ++this->index; }

    item operator * () const { return {this->index, *this->iter_begin}; }

  };

  /*!
  * Helper for lvalues passed to #enumerate().
  */
  template <typename Iterable>
  class enumerator_lvalue_wrapper
  {
    Iterable& iter;
  public:
    enumerator_lvalue_wrapper(Iterable& iter_) : iter(iter_) {}
    enumerator_lvalue_wrapper(enumerator_lvalue_wrapper&& other)
      : iter(other.iter) {}

    auto begin() -> decltype(std::begin(iter)) { return std::begin(iter); }
    auto end() -> decltype(std::end(iter)) { return std::end(iter); }

    auto begin() const -> decltype(std::begin(iter)) { return std::begin(iter); }
    auto end() const -> decltype(std::end(iter)) { return std::end(iter); }
  };


  /*!
  * Enumerate over an iterator.
  */
  template <typename Iterable>
  auto enumerate(Iterable& iter) -> enumerator<enumerator_lvalue_wrapper<Iterable>>
  {
      std::cout << "enumerate(ref)\n";
    return {enumerator_lvalue_wrapper<Iterable>(iter)};
  }

  /*!
  * Enumerate over an rvalue iterator.
  */
  template <typename Iterable>
  auto enumerate(Iterable&& iter) -> enumerator<Iterable>
  {
      std::cout << "enumerate(move)\n";
    return {std::move(iter)};
  }

} // namespace nr



template <typename T>
static void _assert_eq(T const& a, T const& b, char const* msg) {
  if (a != b) {
    std::cerr << msg << std::endl;
    std::cerr << a << "!=" << b << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("bad");
  }
}

#define ASSERT_EQ(a, b) _assert_eq<decltype(a)>((a), (b), #a " == " #b)

//TEST(Iterator, enumerator_rvalue)
int main()
{
  std::size_t index1 = 5;
  for (auto item : nr::enumerate(nr::range<std::size_t>(5, 27))) {
    std::cout << "index1=" << index1 << ", item.index:" << item.index << ", item.value:" << item.value << std::endl;
    ASSERT_EQ(index1 - 5, item.index);
    ASSERT_EQ(index1++, item.value);
  }
  ASSERT_EQ(index1, 27);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the code of nr::enumerate and nr::range?

Comment: You really need to have a [mcve] in the question.  If those links break you question is left incomplete.

Comment: It's all in the Coliru snippet. Sorry when I was unclear about that

Comment: @NathanOliver As I said I wasn't able to simplify the problem. But I could strip down all the comments etc. I guess that would reduce the length of the code..

Comment: @NathanOliver I just included all of the code that I posted on Coliru. Stripping comments doesn't make it easier for people to understand what's going on..

Comment: `enumerator_lvalue_wrapper` and `enumerate(Iterable&)` do not appear to be used in the code .. the MCVE could be shortened by removing them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `enumerator` constructor.

```
enumerator(Iterable&& iter_)
    : iter(std::move(iter_)), index(0), iter_begin(std::begin(iter_))
    , iter_end(std::end(iter_)) {}
```

Here you're setting the iterators `iter_begin` and `iter_end` to the `iter_` parameter, but on the outside it is a temporary which will have expired directly after the initialization. This is what's causing the crash. Rather you should set the iterators to the `iter` data member which is a new object with the moved-from state:

```
enumerator(Iterable&& iter_)
    : iter(std::move(iter_)), index(0), iter_begin(std::begin(iter))
    , iter_end(std::end(iter)) {}
```

Your program now runs to completion: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ddf4ace518ac68e

Comment: Thank you, Sir, for catching this mistake which has been hiding from my radar! :) On a side note, does GCC do "uninitialization" after moving, contrary to Clang and MSVC? Otherwise the error probably would have been completely unnoticed.

Comment: @NiklasR Actually, on second though, it's not the use of move that's a factor but rather the fact that you were initializing the iterators to `iter_` and storing them after the temporary `range<std::size_t>(5, 27)` in the for loop had expired. I'll fix my answer to that effect. To answer your question, no, GCC doesn't do "uninitialization" after a move. Moving happens within the move-constructor and it's entirely up the the class creator how to leave an object after a move. Though the standard does mandate that certain standard classes have a "valid but unspecified" state after a move.

Comment: @NiklasR The reason I say move isn't a factor is because the class `nr::range<size_t>` doesn't contain any user-defined types with move-constructors that could leave the object in a move-from state. Moving is just a copy in this case. If you had used `nr::range<X>` where `X` is some complex user-defined type, then both the fact that you were using `iter_` after it had been moved from, and that you were storing iterators to a temporary both would be valid reasons for the crash.

Comment: You can also try with different optimization flags (for gcc 6.2, -O2 fails, while -O1 works). So it is really dependend on the implementation how this is handled.

Comment: Hmm. Where does the standard prohibit the use of moved-from objects (especially if you know that moving-from doesn't affect the state of your object)?

Comment: @RustyX It doesn't. If moving doesn't affect the state of the object, then using that object after a move is no different than before the move.